# TypeScript error when setting a component's state: Argument of type 'X' is not assignable to parameter of type '() => void'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native

I am having a TypeScript error when calling `setState`:
[image]

That's what I am actually doing:

```
  updateRequests(requests: any, cb:Function|null = null) {
    this.setState(
      {
        requests: {
          ...this.state.requests,
          items: requests,
          loading: false,
        },
      },
      () => {
        if (cb) cb();
      }
    );
```

Here's a Component state:

```
export interface IServersScreenState {
  requests: {
    items: [];
    loading: boolean;
    statuses: {};
    page: number;
    lastPage: number;
    scrollLoading: boolean;
  };
}
```

Don't actually understand why it's happening like that, because I don't have any declaration in the state, that `requests` needs to be look like `()=>void`

here's my setState:

```
  setState<T>(...args: T[]) {
    if (this.__mounted__) {
      //@ts-expect-error spread error
      super.setState(...args) as $TSFixMe;
    }
  }
```

Comment: what's the definition of `this.setState` ?

Answer (score 1):

You've defined setState to accept a generic, and then aren't filling in the generic when it's called. Try replacing

`this.setState(`

with

`this.setState<IServersScreenState>(`

That should get you closer to following the type you've set up.